# Jsmpeg works on jquery, but doesn't work on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**On server:**

```
Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream');
stream = new Stream({
  name: 'name',
  streamUrl: 'rtsp://....',
  wsPort: 9999,
  ffmpegOptions: {
    '-stats': '',
    '-r': 30
  }
})
```

**On Client**

```
const JSMpeg = require ('jsmpeg-player');

componentDidMount() {
    new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9999', {
      canvas: document.getElementById("canvas")
    });
  }

<canvas id="canvas" ref="canvas"></canvas>
```

When i use jsmpeg.min.js on html serverside and clientside is working. I think problem is clientside on react. Please, help me.

Comment: I also use @cycjimmy/jsmpeg-player